# grails how to create a trigger on a relational table (many to many)

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I know that beforeInsert and beforeUpdate and beforeDelete events should be possible, but is there a more convenient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GORM does not provide a mechanism for creating a trigger in a relational database.  The specifics of how to create a trigger in your database will depend on what database you are using, but GORM won't be involved in that.